# issue with controller somehow preventing my view widgets to show

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am trying to display a very simple stackLayout with a label and a button.  It seems like something in my controller is preventing the widgets from showing up...  I tested this view code with another app and it worked fine.  i'm very new to Nativescript and not sure at all where to look for the issue.  I don't get any errors in the console or in my genimotion emulator.  I just see a blank page with the app's name at the top.  Any idea what I can try to figure out what's causing this?

my view code: (app.component.html)

```
<stackLayout>
<label text="Scan or enter a barcode"></label>
<button text="Scan Item" (scan)="scan()></button>
</stackLayout>
```

my controller code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { BarcodeScanner } from "nativescript-barcodescanner";
import { ProductModel } from './models/product';

import { RestService } from './services/rest.service';

let barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template : "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public barcode: number;
    public product: ProductModel;

    public constructor(private restService: RestService) {

    }

    submitBarcode(barcode: number){ 
    this.restService.getProduct(barcode)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        this.product = new ProductModel(res.BaseURI, res.CustomError, res.ProviderName, res.RequestFormData, res.RequestURI, res.ResponseCode, res.AvgQty1, res.AvgQty2, res.AvgQty3, res.BarCode, res.Description, res.POSDescription, res.POSPrice, res.ProductCode, res.PurchCount, res.StockOnHand);
        //console.log("returned product description: " + this.product.Description);
        //console.log(res);
    },
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure" + res);
    }
    );
    //console.log("product: " + product);

}


    public scan() {
        barcodeScanner.scan({
            formats : "EAN_13",
            cancelLabel : "Stop scanning",
            message : "Go scan something Use the volume buttons to turn on the flash",
            preferFrontCamera : false,
            showFlipCameraButton : false
        }).then((result) => {
            this.barcode = +result.text;
            this.submitBarcode(this.barcode);           
        }, (errorMessage) => {
            console.log("Error no scan" + errorMessage);
        });
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        let scanner = new BarcodeScanner();
        scanner.available().then((available) => {
            if(available){
                scanner.hasCameraPermission().then((granted) => {
                    if (!granted){
                        scanner.requestCameraPermission();
                    }
                });
            }
            });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `template` OR `templateUrl` !

Your Component is using the inline-`template`.

If you want to use your template-file, change that line to:

`templateUrl: './app.component.html'`